# Let $S$ be a linearly dependent set. Then, for each $x$ in $S$, is it true that $x$ is in $\operatorname{span}(S\setminus \{x\})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My attempt :

Let $S =$ {$v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n$} ($S$ is finite)

Then there exist $a_i$ which are not all zero such that

$a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 ... + a_nv_n = 0$

Let $v_k$ be an element in $S$ such that $a_k = 0$ in this equation. If no such element exists, then the claim is true. Else ...?

I don't know how to continue, and I don't even think it is true if $a_k = 0$.

Comment: No, it is false. For example, for any non-zero vector $\;v\;$ in *any* linear space, the set $\;S=\{0,\,v\}\;$ is linearly dependent, yet $\;v\notin Span\{0\}\;$ ...

Comment: It is true for _some_ $x$, but not necessarily for all $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. Take $S=\{(1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)\}$. It is linearly dependent, but$$(1,0)\notin\bigl\langle(0,1),(0,-1)\bigr\rangle.$$